# Nether Wart farming in Minecraft 1.0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the new potion brewing system in Minecraft, I thought I'd set up a farm for [Nether Wart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart)s, but there seems to be a logistics problem here.

If I plant 1 Nether Wart on some soul sand, and then later harvest it, I get 1 back.

In other words, there appears to be no way to actually *farm* these. Is this correct?

I have to hunt down strongholds and find fresh sources for them, which I use up when I harvest, and then I have to hunt some more?

Or is there something I'm missing here, some trick to get more than 1 wart out of 1 plant?

Comment: If your problem has been solved, could you checkmark the answer that helped you most?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Harvested [Nether Wart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart) should yield 2-4.  However, this only works if you wait until it is fully grown.

For instance, none of these are fully grown:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not correct. You can farm Nether Warts and if you feel like you need more you can go hunt for more.

Nether Wart will only grow in the Nether and can only be planted on Soul Sand. When left alone, each plant will grow through three distinct stages in a similar fashion to wheat. Each plant has a 0.00407% chance of growing to the next stage every 1/20th of a second, meaning that they can potentially grow very quickly or take as long as several hours to fully develop, so large farms are recommended to maximize one's chances. Factors such as light level, proximity to lava, and fire do not appear to affect the growth rate of Nether Wart. Nether Warts only grow when you are in its render distance. If you aren't, the Nether Wart pauses from growing. It is not affected by bone meal.
As of 1.0.0, Nether Wart can only be grown in the nether, which tends not to be loaded as often for most players, resulting in less chances for Nether Wart to grow.

It's only when you harvest them in their final stage they yield result (dropping more than one).

[image: A screenshot showing the three of four different sizes of nether wart as viewed from the side. Note that the final size is approximately one full block tall.]

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I have a large patch of soulsand by my portal then set it to peaceful, open my inventory and go AFK for an hour. you will end up with far more then you can use since each wart brews three potions.

Answer (score -2):

To farm nether warts you need soul sand and lava[unless torches and can be farmed in the nether or in the other world.] So you can make potions with the nether warts but I don't know what else to do with them when you farm it.

Comment: They don't need light. Also, the OP's problem is that they were trying to harvest too early.